# 2d/CCNode.cpp:1244: error: undefined reference to 'creator::CameraNode::getInstance()'

Tags: cocos2d-x

When build app with cocos2d-x-3.9 which is used in Cocos Creator 1.5.2.

but get the following error.

```
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libMyGame.so
~/proj.android-studio/app/jni/../../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCNode.cpp:1244: error: undefined reference to 'creator::CameraNode::getInstance()'

~/proj.android-studio/app/jni/../../../cocos2d/cocos/./2d/CCNode.cpp:1247: error: undefined reference to 'creator::CameraNode::containsNode(cocos2d::Node*)'
~/proj.android-studio/app/jni/../../../cocos2d/cocos/./base/CCDirector.cpp:1031: error: undefined reference to 'spine::SkeletonBatch::destroyInstance()'
~/proj.android-studio/app/jni/../../../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCRenderer.cpp:885: error: undefined reference to 'creator::CameraNode::getInstance()'
~/proj.android-studio/app/jni/../../../cocos2d/cocos/./renderer/CCRenderer.cpp:893: error: undefined reference to 'creator::CameraNode::getVisibleRect()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 2 sentences in  "cocos/Android.mk"

```
  LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += creator_static

  LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += spine_static
```

such as：

257 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_chipmunk_static

258 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos_zlib_static

259 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += creator_static

260 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += spine_static

"cocos/Android.mk" line 221 of 308 --71%-- col 1